# How to create RSS feed for particular content type in drupal 8?

Tags: views, feeds

I have to create the RSS feed for particular content type and found some module and try to generate some RSS feed but I won't. If you have any idea or if anyone did this Please share with me.

Comment: http://getlevelten.com/blog/kristin-brinner/how-display-rss-feed-drupal-block

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already try this module but it won't work for me and I created RSS using view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can create the views as well for generate the rss feed with following steps:

1. Enable `Serializer` and `RESTful Web Services` module, available in Drupal 8 core.
2. Create views for retrieving the contents of required content type.
3. Select the option **Provide a REST export**, present in the `REST export settings` (present at the bottom of views).
4. Configure the views as per the requirement.

Example:
[image]

Comment: I didn't enable any module actually. Simply I add the feed to view its work fine. Thanks for share your knowledge.

Comment: When following these instructions I get a "Undefined root element: response" error